# Multiple Return Values in Python to Avoid Globals

Tags: python, return-value

I can across the code below which avoids using globals by returning multiple values from a setup function and then passing them to the various other functions from a `main` function.

I've not seen this style of coding before. Is it  a good way to avoid using globals in a Python program?

Are there any potential downsides? Is it "pythonic"?

```
SPACE = ' '  # constant to give a space a name


def InputMaxNumberOfSymbols():
    Number = 0
    while Number % 2 == 0:
        print("How many symbols make the base?")
        Number = int(input("Input an odd number: "))
    return Number


def SetValues():
    Symbol = input("What symbol do you want to use? ")
    MaxSymbols = InputMaxNumberOfSymbols()
    Spaces = (MaxSymbols + 1) // 2
    Symbols = 1
    return Symbol, MaxSymbols, Spaces, Symbols


def OutputChars(Number, Symbol):
    for Count in range(Number):
        print(Symbol, end='')


def AdjustValuesForNextRow(Spaces, Symbols):
    Spaces = Spaces - 1
    Symbols = Symbols + 2
    return Spaces, Symbols


def main():
    ThisSymbol, MaxNumberOfSymbols, NumberOfSpaces, NumberOfSymbols = SetValues()
    while NumberOfSymbols <= MaxNumberOfSymbols:
        OutputChars(NumberOfSpaces, SPACE)
        OutputChars(NumberOfSymbols, ThisSymbol)
        print()  # move to new line
        NumberOfSpaces, NumberOfSymbols = AdjustValuesForNextRow(NumberOfSpaces, NumberOfSymbols)


main()
```

Comment: Defiunitely so. Globals should be avoided in any language.

Comment: Returning multiple values is a common practice used not only to avoid globals.